# Can we disable App level permissions by programming in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, permissions, accessibility

I need to manage app-level permissions that are device-specific.
there are 4 permissions:

1. faceID login
2. camera
3. storage
4. location

What I need to develop is, if I enable-disable switches on these permissions, it should be reflected on app settings too.
for eg. If I have disabled camera permission; it should show disable in settings-> privacy -> camera -> App (disabled)
Is this possible?

Current development:
I have enabled it all by default. and stored it in UserDefaults. Whenever a user wants to access the feature, I check the value stored in UserDefault. Allow if enabled and show a message if disabled.
But disabled doesn't mean it's disabled from the device settings.
I hope I've explained my question properly :/

Comment: You cannot programmatically remove a permission you have been granted. Once you have a permission you have it until the user turns it off in settings.

Comment: What makes you think that your app does not require user's permission for access to those features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot programmatically remove a permission you have been granted.

Once you have a permission you have it until the user turns it off in settings.

Accordingly, it doesn't make sense to provide a UI to disable *permissions* in your app.

What you can do is provide a UI to disable *features* that use those *permissions*. For example, a switch to turn on/off "Login with FaceId" or "Report my location"; if the switch is off your app might still have the permission, but your app won't make use of it.